# How to match/compare 3 columns to another 3 columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, gis

To preface: I don't know if this is even the right question to ask, but I basically need 3 columns to match another 3 columns in Excel.

I have some BBS data that was pre-selected by the professor for the class. Now, they have challenged us to make a map out of the data he's given us; and nicely enough, BBS collects route location data (longitude/latitude). Unfortunately, the given data by the prof does not have long/lat data and it's up to me to figure out which route is which.

The raw BBS data contains the long/lat data, which I would need to extract and put into a .csv file so I can work with it on GIS.

[Image of Dataset I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGlHu.png)

So, I need the columns `A`, `B`, and `C` to match columns in `L`, `M`, and `N`. Then, I would just extract the long/lat data manually. There's 328 long/lat data points I would copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

i think, you need to map "A to B" column cell against Column "L to H".
so best way to this, use vlookup, if it's related to multiple critera then create key of both cell and according use vlookup.

[image: vlookup]

for key see below
[image: key]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't really know how to phrase my question better, but this most definitely helped and allowed me to do what I needed to do!!